# for loop that can for range n, n-1

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am fairly new to python so i need your help to try an figure out how to do this.

I am trying to import data from an excel file to a MySQL database, and i need to import everything but the heather and last row from this file.

at the moment, this is the code:

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows - 1):
    rowid = sheet.cell(r, o).value
    currency_Symbol = cell(r, 1).value
    ....
```

I know that probably it is in this part of the code that i need to do something, but i tried everything that i could think of, and nothing worked.
any thoughts?

important to say that i am using xlrd and MySQLdb, so i need something that work with this modules.

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you're currently getting?

Comment: Thanks for your help colopop, everything is working properly, the main problem is that the last row of the excel file has information that will mess up the report, and i cant import it to MySQL. if it was only one file, i would erase it, but i am trying to adapt the code to do the same thing to 80 files, and in all of them the last line is supposed to be left out.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas

```
pd.read_excel(<parameter>)
pd.to_sql(<parameters>)
```

A quick Sample below with Pandas and SQL Alchemy:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(<<MYSQL COnnection String>>)
df = pd.read_excel("") #https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='tablename',if_exists='append', index=False)
```

You will need to install Pandas and SQLAlchemy Module though. You can google those easily,

Comment: Thank you for your help Rehan, but all my code is based on xlrd and MySQLdb, everything else is working, and i cant afford to adapt the code to Pandas...Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: @P.Costa it will save u a lot of time and effort, look at the sample code above  , hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Rehan, i will.

Comment: It doesn't address the OP's original issue of needing to drop two of the rows. That being said, Pandas is a great library and well worth looking at another time.

Comment: it looked fine to me, but it still imports the last row. in the code that you posted Rehan, can you help me to with"Mysql Connection String"? i have the connection  at the moment looking like this: db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="username", passwd="password", port=0000, db="name of db") how can i change this to have a MYSQL connection string?

Comment: Please refer to : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Comment: @RehanAzher one last question if possible, how can i exclude the first and last rows with your sugestion? cant seem to find it in the documentatio

Comment: @P.Costa You can either exclude it on import or after import. On import, add the parameter `skiprows` e.g. pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", skiprows=[0]). After import, something like df1 = df.iloc[1:-1].

Answer (score 0):

Having run a few tests on one of my own spreadsheets, it looks like a confusion as to what `nrows` means and how it relates to the range index.

The header row is row 0.

By starting your range at 1, you correctly exclude the header (if the header is only 1 row!).

`nrows` is the number of rows. This means if you have 362 rows, `nrows` will be 362. BUT ... if you pass this to range, since `range` starts with 0, you will get "bumped" to the 363rd row. The `nrows -1` you have in your code adjusts this back to the last line of the sheet.

Therefore, to clean your data the way you describe, all you need to do to exclude the header and the last row is to start at row 1 and end at `nrows -2`.

`for r in range(1, sheet.nrows - 2):`